# If the app is launched by touching the push, is there a way to run the code after waiting for the mainPage of app to finish loading?

Tags: ios, swift

Touch Push on my app to move the screen.
It works well if the app is already running.
If the app is off and you touch the app, you will not be able to receive information.
If the app is launched by touching the push, is there a way to run the code after waiting for the main page of my app to finish loading?

`Appdelegate.swift`

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo




    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {

    }

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)


    Execution code when touching push
    }
```

`Execution code when touching push` is executed before mainpage is loaded, and the app is terminated.
Execution code when is there a way to wait for a touching push?

Answer (score 2):

> If the app is launched by touching the push, is there a way to run the
>   code after waiting for the main page of my app to finish loading?

Calling and triggering such `didReceive` delegate method yourself won't be possible, OR let's say wouldn't be ideal.

What you could do with that is to save the data `messageID` or better yet your `userInfo` into your local, say in `UserDefaults`. And then you check it yourself when your home or main screen or root screen has been loaded. If the `UserDefaults` contains push data, then from there, handle it your self. Otherwise, do the normal stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @rmaddy. But why not adding such phrase? I've been seeing phrases like that so I was able to pick it up and add it to my most answers here.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258187/is-it-ok-to-write-hope-that-helps-or-why-is-my-answer-being-edited

Answer (score 1):

To execute specific code after some screen will be loaded/or some logic on this screen will be finished you need to pass your notification through your navigation flow.
I would suggest you to define enum describing your notification events.
And pass this enum to your `UIViewController`

```
enum NavigationRoute {
    case like(userID: Int)
    case friendBirthday(friendId: Int)

    // MARK: - Initializers

    init?(notificationPayload: Any) {
        //
    }
}


class Test: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Vars

    fileprivate var route: NavigationRoute?

    // MARK: - Public

    func configureWithRoute(_ route: NavigationRoute) {
        self.route = route
    }

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let eventRoute = route {
            print("do smth with your push notification logic")
        }
    }
}

let route = NavigationRoute(notificationPayload: 12)
let vc = Test()
vc.configureWithRoute(route)
vc.view // enforce VC to load view, just for testing
```